# Find number of customers and orders and group by month (Bigquery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get  monthly sales numbers in each Country & region.

Also - a number of orders, customers and sales persons in each month with a total amount.

I got stuck as I cannot understand how to make all counts/sum and also group by month as I only have daily data.

I have tried something like this:

```sql
SELECT
orderdate,
  TerritoryID,
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(SalesOrderID)
  FROM
    adwentureworks_db.salesorderheader),
  COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) SalesPersonID,
  SUM(totaldue)
FROM
  adwentureworks_db.salesorderheader
GROUP BY
  OrderDate,
  TerritoryID,
  TotalDue`
```

It should look like this:
[image: example]

Data:
[image: Data]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please use the trunc to round to the first day of each month: `Select date_trunc(orderdate,month), TerritoryID, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) SalesPersonID,  SUM(totaldue),  COUNT(SalesOrderID) over () as whatsthat
FROM
  adwentureworks_db.salesorderheader
GROUP BY 1,2 `

Comment: @Samuel - please refrain from posting code as a comment - it's unformatted and very difficult to read. Post a proper answer instead, with properly-formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st day of a month can be obtained by `date_trunc(orderdate,month)`

For the inner `SELECT`, I do not know what you want to archive. The total number can be obtained by a window function `count(...) over()`.

```
Select 
 date_trunc(orderdate,month),
 TerritoryID,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) as SalesPersonID,
 SUM(totaldue) as totaldue,
 COUNT(SalesOrderID) over () as totalsalesorder_of_whole_table
FROM adwentureworks_db.salesorderheader
GROUP BY 1,2
```